# number format that return numeric value

Tags: php, mongodb

I have number like '5.5'. we want to display like '5.500'.  I could use number format function for this. But it is returning string.

```
$total_charges =number_format((float)$number, 3, '.', '');
```

When I use string value in mongodb so its not sort or filter in proper way.

```
array('total_charges'=>array('$gte'=>100,'$lte'=>200))
```

There is any function like number format that return numeric value with particular decimal places.

Comment: you don't need to store `5.500`. Store it as 5.5. When your re-tribe it to client hand then use number format to show like 5.500

Answer (score 0):

"5.500" simply cannot be a number. This is a representation of a number. You said yourself "we want to display like" !

Comment: I don't know about mongodb, but I am pretty sure this the number format is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo sprintf("%1\$.3f",1.25);
```

the result is : 1.250

Comment: echo sprintf("%6.3f",22.25); the function return a float number,the 6 present will display 6 number,include '.',the 3 present the after '.' have 3 number

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.